# could you identify this Orchid?

Tags: identification, houseplants, orchids

[image: unidentified plant]

If been told that this is an Amaryllis but I'm very doubtful.

Thanks to the clue given by @GardenGems I have finally narrowed it down to bromeliads

[image]

[image]

It has a baby that looks slightly different 
[image]

UPDATE:

I had a look at the roots and I'm confused..... they look like orchid roots! 
The growing medium is 40% wood chips!

The roots are flexible like thick string with a coat around them almost like a pre filter! 
Inside of the 1 cm coat/tunnel is ample space for the 3 milliliter thick roots to move around

The coat is like dry mushrooms, almost spongy and measures less then a milliliter thick but completely surrounds the inner root all the way to the tip.

Also I noticed what looks like a fungal infestation with in the filter of the root coat but it might be a symbiotic relationship as the roots with in the  coat still look healthy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The plant is battered and overwatered and cold let's see if I can help it reverse its miss fortune any advice is most welome.

thanks to @polypipe-wrangler i took a look at the pot and its on the pot 
[image]

Comment: I think it is a epiphytic plant.  Woodchips are commonly used for both larger tropical plants & epiphytes.   It is good medium to avoid compacting.  It is also cheap.  You are right the fungus is most likely a mycorhizzal fungi.

Comment: The roots have a coating like a wire....a space to keep the mycorrhizae alive?  Wtf my mind is blown

Comment: The textures of the coating itself resembles mushrooms

Comment: Turned out it was getting to much moisture around the roots  and bad temperatures but I'm gonna revive it!

Comment: Go ahead and pull-out dead roots. If you're letting it dormant in winter without artificial heat & light, don't do more than that. Just remove as much dead roots as you can and repot it in a better draining soil. Don't water it for a few days. This looks like cymbidium. Here is a helpful link: https://grndoordesign.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/how-to-pot-and-divide-orchids/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really looks like a Cymbidium orchid, one of the hardy species perhaps. The roots in loose clothing matches, and the pseudobulbs of the dead stems.

Comment: you wont belive this but  it says it on the pot! Cymbidium

Comment: Hiding in plain sight -- Now I see the writing.

Answer (score 1):

The stem and the connection of the leaves to the stem looks different. It is possibly a Nolina or a Yucca, completely unrelated genera.

Nolinas will develop a caudex. If not, this may be a juvenile form. Both genera will develop a trunk anyway and look palm-like. Clivias remain short, they offset at ground level rather than growing tall, and their roots are thick and succulent.

Comment: Thanks @Christmas_Snow I'll take a photo of the roots as it needs repotting.  Its difficult to ID as it is so battered.